# Redirect without changing the browser url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following url,

```
www.example.com/home.php and
 www.example.com/login.php
```

When ever I redirect to anyof these pages from php , the url of the browser should remain www.example.com.

I have tried,but I could not do anything due to lack of knowledge in mod_rewite.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the php code used for these redirect ?

Comment: I used `header('Location:/home.php')` for the both depending upon the condition

Comment: With htaccess you can only remove file extension. 
If you want to only show  www.example.com, load the content from ajax or iframe.

Comment: Or u can use ajax to update container content...

Comment: Dear @user3357227 are you find the solution.If then please guide me in the comment.Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the page after login, to the same URL when the user was not login (we assume www.example.com), that's easy:

in www.example.com it loads the index.php, so we should change index.php's content.

It has this content when the user who is not logged in, first visit it:

```
include("htmls/index.html"); // index.html could contain whatever you like
```

But you add this condition, the above line is inside a condition:

```
if(isset($_POST['form-submit']))
{
   // do the login process and if success
   include("htmls/index_loggedin.html");
}
else if(is_user_logged_in()===true)
{
  include("htmls/index_loggedin.html"); // 
}
else
{
  include("htmls/index.html"); // means the user has not submitted anything and is also not logged in

}
```

The above code says that if the user has logged in, process his/her login and then include
a view which is for logged in users, also if the user is already logged, also shows him/her the view which is for logged in users, otherwise, if the user is not logged, nor has sent no request of loggin in, then show him a basic view for unlogged users. I have assumed the submit button of your form is named "form-submit".

However the above naming is just for sake of clarity. For instance, you can combine index.html and index_loggedin.html into one view_index.php and then also duplicate the conditions of the main index.php to also the view_index.php.

A last note is that, you should separate the code and the view as fully as possible.

Comment: Hi I want know where to add this code because right i am getting some error

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with mod_rewrite. How should Apache know if you want home.php or login.php? You probably want to use AJAX to load the files in the background and then display the content.

Comment: I dont want to redirect, I just want the url to be remain www.example.com when I redirect to /home.php or /login.php, just like  for eg: facebook.com

Comment: Like I said, you can't do that with mod_rewrite, since the user needs to tell the webserver, what he wants. Facebook uses AJAX (Javascript) to load the pages.

Comment: I dont agree with you, You can see when the user has already logged in it will redirect to the home page without changing the url and if not logged in it will redirect to login page without changing the url

Comment: Yes, because Facebook uses Javascript to load the pages and manipulate the url.

Answer (score -1):

You should use iframe html tag in page layout for the url of the browser remain www.example.com, when user navigates between pages. not redirect nor rewrite are not suitable for these purposes.